# vb.net Sorting Dates

Tags: vb.net, sorting, date

I'm trying to sort a list of objects by a date property, but the dates aren't ordered correctly.  I've tried passing them to an array and using `Array.Sort` and I've also tried passing them to a list and using `List.OrderBy(Function(x) x.requestClose)`, where the property `requestClose` is a date, but I get the same result.

For example, say I have the following dates:

```
11/9/2015,
11/20/2015,
11/10/2015
```

What I want is the list to be arranged as:

```
11/9/2015,
11/10/2015,
11/20/2015
```

but what I'm getting is:

```
11/10/2015,
11/20/2015,
11/9/2015
```

The date property is declared as:

```
Public requestClose As Date
```

and later used with:

```
DateTime.TryParse(formAddEquip.dtpCxDate.Value, newEquip.requestClose)
```

I was able to get it to work by creating a separate sort, specifically for the case when sorting by the date.  The issue, as pointed out by people here, is that the `keyArray()` was being assigned a String and not a Date.  Is there a convenient way to declare this array to avoid having to call what is essentially the same sub-routine that differs only by array variable type?

```
Public Sub dateSort()
    Dim thisEquipList As New classEquipCollection
    thisEquipList.Clear()

    Dim keyArray() As Date 'THIS IS WHERE IT WAS PREVIOUSLY DECLARED A STRING; string sorting is still needed for other sorting, such as by equip.name
    '
    ReDim keyArray(0 To project.equipList.Count - 1)
    'create an array of the search terms

    For i = 1 To project.equipList.Count
        keyArray(i - 1) = project.equipList(i - 1).requestClose
    Next

    Array.Sort(keyArray)

    'remove duplicats in the key array
    Dim dupeFound As Boolean
    Dim newKeyArray() As String
    ReDim newKeyArray(0 To 0)
    Dim noDupeIndex As Integer
    'new key array holds only non-duplicates
    For i = 0 To UBound(keyArray)
        dupeFound = False
        For j = (i + 1) To UBound(keyArray)
            If keyArray(j) = keyArray(i) Then
                dupeFound = True
            End If
        Next j
        'if a unique key, add it to the non-duplicate array
        If dupeFound = False Then
            ReDim Preserve newKeyArray(0 To noDupeIndex)
            newKeyArray(noDupeIndex) = keyArray(i)
            noDupeIndex = noDupeIndex + 1
        End If

    Next i
    'match the equipment item to the search term and 
    For i = 0 To UBound(newKeyArray)
        For Each item In project.equipList
            If newKeyArray(i) = item.requestClose Then
                thisEquipList.Add(item)
            End If
        Next
    Next
    'now that the list is sorted, assign it to project equiplist
    project.equipList.Clear()
    For i = 0 To thisEquipList.Count - 1
        project.equipList.Add(thisEquipList(i))
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the data type of `dateProperty`?  Is it a string?  If so, make it a `date` instead.

Comment: You need to show the code - it looks like they are not actual Date types, but strings ("9" is more than "10").  [Edit] your post, dont add code to comments.

Comment: I believe they are correctly cast as date types. I used DateTime.TryParse(formAddEquip.dtpCxDate.Value, newEquip.requestClose)

Comment: we need to know the object property type...that code may not do anything - a DTP value *is* a date

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding.  Here is how the object property is declared Public requestClose As Date

Comment: one more time. [Edit] your post means [Edit] your post so that code formats properly.  Show the code used to sort and the object property

Comment: We're looking for the definition of `dateProperty` not `requestClose`.

Comment: that tryparse is not needed - the Value of a DateTimePicker is a DateTime type.  Still need the actual sorting code

Comment: You can get rid of *all* this code with a single call to [Distinct()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb348436(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Interestingly, when I try to use the Distinct() method, I'm still getting duplicates repopulating in the ListView.  I'm sure there's a way to use the method to get it to work, but my issues may involve the fact that the equip.name property is unique, but others aren't necessarily so (e.g. they may have the same .requestDate property)

Comment: you can replace all that code with: `Dim ByDate = equipList.OrderBy(Function(d) d.requestClose).ToList`  Assuming a) requestclose is a proper date type and b) `equipList` is a `List(of Equipment)`  The result will be a new `List(Of Equipment)` with the items in date order

Comment: @coolhand Simple `Distinct()` doesn't work because it's not using the `requestClose` property as the key, and instead just calling `GetHashCode()` (unless you have a custom `EqualityComparer` or `.Equals()` overload in play). You can force this using `GroupBy()` instead, and though the code is a bit more complicated than `Distinct()` it's still a **huge** win over what you have now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old now, but showed up today in the unanswered view, and the entire method can be *greatly* simplified:

```
Public Sub dateSort()
    project.equipList = project.equipList.OrderBy(Function(e) e.requestClose).
                           GroupBy(Function(e) e.requestClose).
                           Select(Function(g) g.First()).
                           ToList()
End Sub
```

Note this assumes that .Net's Linq operators all use stable sorts and processes that will preserve the original order. I believe this is currently the case, but it hasn't always been so and, while likely to remain unchanged for the foreseeable future, could change again. If stable sorts can not be guaranteed, you may need to add an additional `.OrderBy()` within the `Select()` to ensure choosing the correct item, and then move the main `OrderBy()` to after the `Select()`.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the [OrderBy Extension Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534966(v=vs.100).aspx), you need to ensure you're using the result set to see the correct ordering.

```
Dim lstSortedList As List(Of YourObject) = lstOriginal.OrderBy(Function(objTarget) objTarget.requestClose).ToList()
```